# Javascript carousel works, but not as I would like

Tags: javascript, carousel

Here is the code for my javascript carousel:

```js
var carousel = document.getElementById("carosello");

function myMoveLeft() {
  carousel.scrollTo(-50, 0);
}

function myMoveRight() {
  carousel.scrollTo(+50, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="arrowLeft" onclick="myMoveLeft()">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-left fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="caroselloContainer">
    <div id="carosello">
      <div class="caroselloCard">
        <img class="active first" src="..." alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="caroselloCard">
        <img src="..." alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="caroselloCard">
        <img class="last" src="..." alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="arrowRight" onclick="myMoveRight()">
    <i class="fas fa-chevron-right fa-5x"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

This works but only on the first click. How do I make it work at all clicks?

I would like it so that every time I click, `scrollTo` increases by 50. Something that simulates scrolling would be even better, but the first solution would also suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You can scrollPosition in a variable and then increase/decrease it.

What happens now is no matter how many times you click, your scrollPosition is set to `-50` or `50`, you have to keep updating that values on clicks.

Like

```
<script>
  var carousel = document.getElementById("carosello");
  var scrollPosition = 0;
  function myMoveLeft() {
    scrollPosition = scrollPosition - 50;
    carousel.scrollTo(scrollPosition, 0);
  }
  function myMoveRight() {
    scrollPosition = scrollPosition + 50;
    carousel.scrollTo(scrollPosition, 0);
  }
</script>
```